# CSS keyframe animation timing function across multiple iterations

Tags: css

I have carousel with animation and specified animation speed:

```
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.27,.97,.86,1);

@keyframes back-y-spin {
  0%     { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
  100%   { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
}
```

I wonder how could I rotate it 2, 3, etc. times but apply timing function to entire rotation. For instance, if I specify `animation-iteration-count: 2;` carouser started, then going slower, then stops and then repeated - faster, slower, stopped.

What I want: carousel started, speed increased then rotated N times then speed decreased and it is stopped.

Here is example I worked with: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgeOEQ

Comment: Just rotate `720deg` instead of `360deg`?

Comment: @JohanKarlssonif I understood you right it will rotated then only for 30 deg. Not what I want. In need to rotate literally from 360*3deg to 0 deg.

Comment: `0% {transform: rotateY(720deg);} 100% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `transform: rotate(calc(360deg * 3));`. Example below.

```css
.shape {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  
  animation: rotate 5s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.9,.1,.1,.9);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotate(calc(360deg * 6)); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```